# r filter() issue: plotly vs ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, r-plotly

I am starting to learn interactive data viz and basic data analysis with R (mainly plotly).
I am having an issue while using the dplyr function filter() while plotting with plotly in R.
here is an example using the gapminder dataset:

```
library(gapminder)


# filter by year and continent
gapminder_2002_asia <- gapminder %>%
  filter(year== 2002 & continent == "Asia")
# plot gpd/capita bar chart using plotly
gapminder_2002_asia %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_bars(x= ~country, y = ~gdpPercap, color = ~country)
```

this is the results: all the world countries present in the initial data set are on the x axis:
plotly graph as image

[image]

On the other hand, if  just make a static graph with ggplot, I only have the asian countries appearing on the x axis:

```
gapminder_2002_asia %>%
  ggplot(aes(country, gdpPercap, fill = country)) +
  geom_col()
```

ggplot graph

[image]

I really do not understand how this is happening as they both come from the same df..

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `plotly` is taking all the levels inside the country variable while `ggplot2` only takes the available values in your dataset. So, to get same results, yu can use this:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
#Plotly
gapminder_2002_asia %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_bars(x= ~country, y = ~gdpPercap, color = ~country)
```

Output:

[image]

And with `ggplot2`:

```
#ggplot2
gapminder_2002_asia %>%
  ggplot(aes(country, gdpPercap, fill = country)) +
  geom_col()+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=levels(gapminder_2002_asia$country))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:** In order to get the same output in `plotly` you could use something like this, which will be similar to your `ggplot2` initial code for plotting:

```
#Plotly 2
gapminder_2002_asia %>%
  mutate(country=as.character(country)) %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_bars(x= ~country, y = ~gdpPercap, color = ~country)
```

Output:

[image]

The key to tackle is the factors in your dataset.

Another option can be `fct_drop()` from `forcats` (many thanks and credit to **@user2554330**):

```
library(forcats)
#Plotly 2
gapminder_2002_asia %>%
  mutate(country=fct_drop(country)) %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_bars(x= ~country, y = ~gdpPercap, color = ~country)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually what I wanted to obtain was the opposite, meaning only the asian countries in my Plotly graph..

Comment: @Vivvi Hi, please check my last update and let me know if that works for you!

Comment: @Vivvi please check the updated part of the solution at the end, where I included a new code!

Comment: yes it works thanks ! ..though I don't really get why, as normally the levels were filtered out of the initial dataset?

Comment: Factors have a `levels` attribute that can contain values that are not present (so you can have 0 counts in tables).  `filter` leaves the levels alone.  Changing to character loses it.  You could also use `fct_drop(country)` to stay as a factor but with no empty levels; by default `ggplot2` scales do something like that.

Comment: @user2554330 It is a great suggestion, I will update with credits to you!

Answer (score 1):

Very odd.

As an alternative while you debug that code, why not try using ggplotly()?

E. G.

```
p <- gapminder_2002_asia %>%
ggplot(aes(country, gdpPercap, fill = country)) +
geom_col()

plotly::ggplotly(p)
```

I'd be curious which version of the plot came out the far end!